# android: How to set margin/padding between EditText custom background and InputTextLayout Label?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, android-custom-drawable

Well I want to set margin/padding between EditText and InputTextLayout Label on Pressed State.

Here's my image of - [desired design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqYPu.jpg)

**Main Xml** code - `

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/headphones_3" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/password_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/floating_hint_margin"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/floating_hint_margin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Though right now i applied custom theme only to 'Password" TextInputLayout.!

Here is the code of **edit_text_style**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- focused state -->
<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#80FFFFFF" />
        <stroke android:width=".5dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- normal state -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="22dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

The result which I got - [Resulted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAIfO.png)

As you can see the Label goes up to cursor and there's no padding between Label and EditText background.

And how to set Label to where the EditText Background starts ( as it's on top of cursor right now )?

( Sorry for my bad english )

**UPDATE :** Let me explain you - See those images again.! What i want to set padding between TextInputLayout label ( which is password here when you focus it ). What you guys said was creating padding between custom drawable ( which is edit_text_style here ) cursor and Label, but i want padding between the drawable I added and Label ( password text which appear when it's on focused state ) & Also want to set Label position as it's goes upward to cursor start.!

Comment: Use padding in edittext

Comment: android:paddingTop="10dp"   for top or  android:padding="10dp" for all

Comment: It's not working @Vickyexpert. I guess it's because of background which i added. As it increase height between cursor & label ( but not between background & label )

Comment: @Er.Arjunsaini see the updated question ( slightly made it clear now :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **@Ansh.... You are set the drawable to your TextInputLayout and take padding to both edittext and TextInputLayout.....**

In your way it's is not work well.... if you want to do like that you want with textinputlayout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="10dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_label"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:padding="10dp"

            android:visibility="visible">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/input_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"

             />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

**And also in your drawable take only one rectangle or Rounded for better View**

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a custom style to your EditText (the ones where you need to have a padding `onPressedState`) :

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

And the style :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <item android:state_focused="true"
             android:state_pressed="true"
             android:drawable="@drawable/next_white">
             <inset android:insetLeft=""YOUR_PADDING_IN_DP dp"/>
```

Source : [android:drawableLeft margin and/or padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337371/androiddrawableleft-margin-and-or-padding)

For the margin, it isn't possible to do it with drawable, but you can still define an animation which will do the trick :

In res/anim, create a **margin_animation.xml** :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"              android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
               <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="100%" />
    </set>
```

Source : [In Android, is it possible to set the margin from the drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286923/in-android-is-it-possible-to-set-the-margin-from-the-drawable)

Comment: This is not what i asked for.! thank you though. I want padding between drawable background and TextInputLayout label and also want to move label position as it always goes upward to cursor.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you.
If I understood you, you need margin between password EditText and its label ? If so, you should try to apply a **margin="8dp"** for your TextInputLayout corresponding to the Password EditText
For the cursor padding, you should add padding="your_padding" to your EditText I guess

Comment: Let me explain you - See those images again.! What i want to set padding between TextInputLayout label ( which is password here when you focus it ). What you guys said was creating padding between custom drawable ( which is edit_text_style here ) cursor and Label, but i want padding between the drawable I added and Label ( password text which appear when it's on focused state ).

Comment: If you want your custom background and label being spaced, you need to add **<inset insetTop/Bottom/Left/Right="a_padding_value"/>** in one of your **<item> tags** in **edit_text_style.xml**